# Error : can't convert char[6] * to char *

Tags: c

I am playing with string and pointers. It opens an another world of programming for me but I am not getting the logic behind it.

> Error : can't convert `char[6] *` to `char *`

```
void main() { 
  int arr[]={1,2,3,4,5}; 
  char ch[]= {'a','b','c','d','e',0}; 
  char ch1[]= "abcde"; 
  char *ch3="this a"; 

  clrscr(); 
  ch3 = &ch1; 
  printf("%c",*(ch3)); 
  getch(); 
}
```

Comment: My crystal ball is broken and I'm not able to tell what code causes the error. :P

Comment: You can't convert an array of char pointers to a char pointer because they are incompatible types.

Comment: Please show your code, we are not [clairvoyants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clairvoyance)

Comment: Dont show code in comments but instead [edit] your question.

Comment: `ch3 = &ch1;` -> `ch3 = ch1;`, `ch1` _is_ already a memory address. And you can remove the parentheses her : `*(ch3)` -> `*ch3`, it's not wrong, but they are useless. I suggest you read the chapters dealing with pointers and with strings in your C text book.

Comment: thanks Michale Walz for helping me to find out my blunder

Comment: @LethalProgrammer: The string literal cannot be modified, sure, but `ch3` can be set to point to a different memory location.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is in the line

```
ch3 = &ch1;
```

The expression `&ch1` has type "pointer to 6-element array of `char`", or `char (*)[6]`.  `ch3` has type `char *`.  The two types are not compatible, hence the error.  To fix this, drop the `&` from `&ch1`:

```
ch3 = ch1;
```

The expression `ch1` has type "6-element array of `char`", or `char [6]`.  Since it's not the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, it will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type `char *`, and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.

There are other issues with this code, but that's what's causing your error.